# How to replace whole document if password is incorrect?

Tags: javascript

Ok so I'm trying to make a security such that when the password typed is incorrect the whole document will get replaced by the words "Invalid Password. Access Denied." But it's not working...

```
<p>Lol.</p>

<script type="text/JavaScript">
var p = prompt("Please input password before proceeding.")
if (p !== password){
    document.write("<html><body><p>Invalid Password. Access Denied.</p></body></html>"); 
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `password` declared?

Comment: *"But it's not working"*  would mean errors thrown...what are they? Those errors are your clues for debugging. Doesn't appear that the variable `password` is defined. Whole idea is fairly useless since it means you have to expose this password in the browser

Comment: also, I'm sure this is just for learning purposes, but you should never under any circumstances be doing password validation on the client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`password` is an undeclared variable, try `'password'` with the `''` marks to use it as a String.

```js
var p = prompt('Please input password before proceeding.')

if (p !== 'password'){
    document.write("<html><body><p>Invalid Password. Access Denied.</p></body></html>"); 
} else {
    document.write("<html><body><p>Valid Password. Access Granted.</p></body></html>"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is you haven't declared `password`.

```
if (p !== password)
```

You need is:

```
if (p !== 'some text')
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the password variable. For demo I have hard-coded it.
Also you don't need to include `html` & `body` tag inside `document.write`

```
var p = prompt("Please input password before proceeding.")
var password= "somepassword";
if (p !== password){
    document.write("<p>Invalid Password. Access Denied.</p>"); 
}
```

[JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8eLfo8kb/)

If you include `html & body` tag inside the `document.write` there will be nested `html` & `body`
 [image: DOM]